# Connect Onelogin to application database for SSO

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I'm trying to implement SSO(Single Sign-on) using Onelogin PHP toolkit. I have 3 different applications. If I log into one application, I should automatically log into other applications as well. I've implemented [this documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php).

I get this after logging in successfully:
you have the following attributes:

```
Name                 Values
User.FirstName       Ekta
PersonImmutableID   
User.LastName        Garg
memberOf    
User.email           ekta@abc.com
```

My Questions :

1. How can I integrate the application database in `onelogin`? 
   using Active directory? How to link MySQL server to the active directory on Linux server?
2. How can integrate multiple databases in `onelogin` to access multiple applications by logging into the system only once?

I am new to SAML and SSO, so maybe I am missing some big complex part. Please advise me if it's simple as what I am thinking or that I am missing something and I will need to use some of these modules.

Answer (score 0):

You may migrate your users account to OnoLogin and only use OneLogin as the user data source.

To import them you can use:

- CSV. https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202123184-Importing-Updating-and-Deleting-Users-Using-a-CSV-File
- OneLogin API. https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-user

Once done you may disable from your apps the ability to register new users and force them to use OneLogin registration functionality....or only let one app with that action and sync user using OneLogin API.